# the show() function gives me 15 & I understand but why does the print(x) function return 13 I don't get it I am new to python can you pls help me

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to understand *global and local variables in python* and tried out the below-mentioned code but for some reason, the **show()** statement runs fine and I understand that but the **print(x)** statement below the show() prints **13** while I was **expecting** it to print **15**

```
 def show():
        x=10
        x+=5
        print(x)

    show()
    
    print(x)
```

Comment: Is this the entire code? Was `x` initialized before defining the `show` function?

Comment: I'm getting an error regardless of indentation from your code

Comment: The value 15 is available only inside function as it's scope is function. It doesn't modify x value outside the function.

Comment: @12944qwerty  if I define x before the show function then it gives an unbound local error. as for the entire code is considered I am running this in jupyter notebook and this is the entire cell

Comment: I get a recursion error or `NameError` since `x` was never defined. If I prepend `x = 15` before the entire code, it works. This is non-reproducible for me

Comment: @12944qwerty I tried it on another ide  but that just throws an error saying undefined x

x=10
def show():
    global x
    x+=6
    print(x)

this code works as I specify x as global even on the other ide but I am just not able to understand how is the earlier one wrong and this one right.....

Comment: See [this](https://replit.com/@12944qwerty/SO-testing-repo#foo.py) where you inital code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That print statement outside the function should not work at all. If you define a variable inside of a function you cant call it outside of it.

Also if your code looks like this:

```
x = 13

def show():
    x = 10
    x += 5
    print(x)

show()

print(x)
```

the second print statement will still return 13, because by writing `x = 10` you are creating a new variable named x inside the function, which will not be accessible outside this function.

Answer (score 0):

x is probably defined before the function
try to not use the same variable name more than once

assuming x is not defined before this, this code should work

```
def show():
  x = 10
  x += 5
  return x
show()
print(x)
```